# Multiple Wildcard conditions on same field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for something equivalent to this sql in elasticsearch.

`select * from contact where lower(fullname_phone) like 'para1%para2%para3%';`

I have tried something like this, but there are allways two many matches. All three parameters should match for a valid document

```
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "contact.fullname_phone": "john*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "contact.fullname_phone": "do*"
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "contact.fullname_phone": "123456*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the should clauses must match then you can add this after the should [] block

```
 "minimum_should_match" : 3
```

Alternatively, if the para1, para2 and para3 substrings will always show up in order, then you can combine all the three in one must wildcard expression

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "contact.fullname_phone": {
                        "value": "para1*para2*para3*"
                    }
                }
            }
         ]
    }
}
```